# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and am trying to create a stored procedure that will populate a table with the code below:

```
DROP TABLE Times CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE Times (
    sale_day DATE NOT NULL,
    day_type VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (sale_day));


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Time_Procedure
AS
    l_sale_date date;
    temp_value varchar2(5);
CURSOR c1 IS SELECT SALE_DATE FROM SALES;

BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO l_sale_date;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        SELECT to_char(to_date(l_sale_date), 'DY') into temp_value from 
dual;
        IF l_sale_date LIKE '01-JAN-%' OR l_sale_date LIKE '21-JAN-%' OR 
           l_sale_date LIKE '18-FEB-%' OR l_sale_date LIKE '28-MAY-%' 
           OR l_sale_date LIKE '04-JUL-%' OR l_sale_date LIKE '03-SEP-%' OR 
           l_sale_date LIKE '08-OCT-%' OR l_sale_date LIKE '11-NOV-%' 
           OR l_sale_date LIKE '22-NOV-%' OR l_sale_date LIKE '25-DEC-%'  
THEN
            INSERT INTO Times values(l_sale_date,'Holiday');
        ELSE IF temp_value='MON' OR temp_value ='TUE' OR temp_value='WED' OR 
temp_value='THU' OR temp_Value='FRI' THEN
            INSERT INTO Times values(l_sale_date,'Weekday');
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO Time values(l_sale_date,'Weekend');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

But I keep getting the following error:

LINE/COL    ERROR

---

20/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

20/13    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I have been looking at this for sometime and cannot figure out what is wrong with my code to result in error.

Comment: `20/13 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` at line 13: `CURSOR c1 IS SELECT SALE_DATE FROM SALES;` - table **sales** does not exist - the error message is clear.

Comment: @krokodilko: the error is on line 20 column 13, not the other way around.  Also, line numbers start from the first line of the procedure. 
Assuming all those conditions in `IF` statements are on the same line, then line 20 is the line `INSERT INTO Time ...`.  The error is fairly clear here: the table name has been misspelled.

Comment: The error message in your question title differs from the error message in your question.  Have you resolved that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

You have a typo: the third INSERT statement is

```
INSERT INTO Time
```

whereas the other statements are

```
INSERT INTO Times
```

The error in your question title has a different cause:

> Encountered the symbol “end-of-file” errors

Indicates a syntax error. This line

```
ELSE IF
```

tells the PL/SQL compiler you're creating a **nested IF statement**. So it expects an END IF to match that IF plus an END IF for the outer block. Like this:

```
IF l_sale_date LIKE '01-JAN-%' 
    ...
ELSE IF temp_value='MON' 
      ...
     ELSE -- this goes with the nested IF
     ...
     END IF;  -- this goes with the nested IF
END IF;  -- this is the clause you're missing
```

However it seems likely that you're just trying to implement a standard one level switch. In which case you need to know that the PL/SQL is ELSIF not ELSE IF. So like this:

```
IF l_sale_date LIKE '01-JAN-%' 
    ...
ELSIF temp_value='MON' 
      ...
ELSE -- this goes with the starting IF
     ...
END IF;
```

Alternatively you may wish to use the CASE statement, which has the same structure but is more in line with other programming langauages.

```
CASE
   WHEN l_sale_date LIKE '01-JAN-%' 
    ...
   WHEN temp_value='MON' 
      ...
   ELSE
     ...
END CASE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed version - `times` not `time`, `to_char` not `to_date`, `elsif` not `else if` etc). I've also changed it to use a cursor FOR loop instead of all that opening, fetching and closing, moved `temp_value` into the cursor and given it a proper name (semantics is everything in this job), and replaced the `or` list with the handy `in ()` construction. And since you are starting out, you might even avoid getting into the habit of coding in uppercase which sadly afflicts our industry.

```
create or replace procedure time_procedure
as
begin
    for r in (
        select sale_date, to_date(sale_date, 'DY') as day_name
        from   sales
    )
    loop
        if r.sale_date like '01-JAN-%'
            or r.sale_date like '21-JAN-%'
            or r.sale_date like '18-FEB-%'
            or r.sale_date like '28-MAY-%'
            or r.sale_date like '04-JUL-%'
            or r.sale_date like '03-SEP-%'
            or r.sale_date like '08-OCT-%'
            or r.sale_date like '11-NOV-%'
            or r.sale_date like '22-NOV-%'
            or r.sale_date like '25-DEC-%'
        then
            insert into times(sale_day, day_type)
            values (r.sale_date, 'Holiday');

        elsif r.day_name in ('MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI') then
            insert into times(sale_day, day_type)
            values (r.sale_date, 'Weekday');

        else
            insert into times(sale_day, day_type)
            values (r.sale_date,'Weekend');
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

However, you should never assume date formats or languages. One day, the procedure could get called by someone with Spanish desktop settings, and the weekend days will be 'SÁB' and 'DOM' instead of 'SAT' and 'SUN', and the default date format might be `YYYY-MM-DD` or something else.

Also, if we shorten day names to one letter and specify English, then weekend dates are just `'S'`, so here is a refactored version:

```
create or replace procedure time_procedure
as
begin
    for r in (
        select sale_date
             , to_char(sale_date,'DD-MM') as date_str
             , substr(to_char(sale_date, 'DY', 'nls_date_language = English'),1,1) as day_name
        from   sales
    )
    loop
        if r.date_str in
            ( '01-01'
            , '21-01'
            , '18-02'
            , '28-05'
            , '04-07'
            , '03-09'
            , '08-10'
            , '11-11'
            , '22-11'
            , '25-12' )
        then
            insert into times(sale_day, day_type)
            values (r.sale_date, 'Holiday');

        elsif r.day_name = 'S' then
            insert into times(sale_day, day_type)
            values (r.sale_date,'Weekend');

        else
            insert into times(sale_day, day_type)
            values (r.sale_date, 'Weekday');
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

If this wasn't a learning exercise for PL/SQL, you could do the whole thing in SQL:

```
insert into times(sale_day, day_type)
select sale_date
     , case when to_char(sale_date,'DD-MM') in
           ( '01-01', '21-01', '18-02', '28-05', '04-07', '03-09', '08-10', '11-11', '22-11', '25-12' )
           then 'Holiday'
       when to_char(sale_date, 'DY', 'nls_date_language = English') like 'S%'
           then 'Weekend'
       else
           'Weekday'
       end as day_type
from   sales;
```